# How can I improve response time if the remote server is located very far physical distance

Tags: server, architecture, system, low-latency

I want to know how to construct servers physically in this situation.

Let's assume that my service provides in the USA.

And my business is quite successful so, I want to expand my business location in Asia.

but I don't want to localized service, so I just got some API server in Asia to provide service which is just use API that located in headquater, but my main components are still in the USA.

But the problem is that my API which is located in Asia needs to call head-quater API which is located in the USA, and the response is quite often slow because of far physical distance.

so In this situation, How can I overcome?

In my opinion, I get some CDN for static contents. but I have no idea how to improve the API response time problem which is originated from physical distance.

If it is a stupid question, please understand, I'm quite a newbie in architect.

**EDIT:**
Also, How can I construct database replication in this situation.
If I get a replication which is replicate from the USA in Asia, I think the replication performance is quite poor because of phisical distance.
How Amazon or any global service construct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication performance can be quite poor.  It is important to understand how much of your data is changing so that you can estimate the bandwidth required and understand whether your replication can keep up.

Amazon and other global services deal with this via a combination of replication, edge-caching (CDN), and other methodologies that bring the data closer to the consumer.

As a first step, you also might want to look at just making your API more coarse-grained.  The fewer calls you have to make, the higher the performance (as the problem is likely latency, not bandwidth).  See if you can batch things up instead of handling them one-at-a-time.

You also can look critically at caching.  Instead of making your read-only API calls all the time, introduce some cache-control headers to specify the acceptable age of your requests.  A lot of data is very static, things like user data, departments, product-info etc... Some of this data can leverage caching layers to become much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AWS and want to host main components in a specific region, then you may think of hosting it yourself in EC2(s) [as Origin Server] in the region of your choice and use Cloudfront (CDN) to serve the content globally. AWS employs their own High Speed Backbone Network to reduce latency between geographically distant locations, by reducing no of Network hops.

From a caching standpoint, as Rob rightly said, Cloudfront performs different caching mechanisms for hot objects, warm objects (edge-caching, regional-caching); Also the Origin servers can send minimum expiration time and maximum expiration time over HTTP Headers to define Caching TTL.

If however, you don't want to use the advantage of High Speed Backbone Network, you should consider application design of your endpoints and functionality keeping latency as a constraint; and use appropriate TTL for caching of objects and define appropriate caching strategy, keeping in mind the R/W ratio of your application.